# Reassign a shared pointer with operator = causes memory leak?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I have a basic question about shared pointers, in the next example code:

```
int main() {
 std::shared_ptr<int> sp;  // empty
 std::shared_ptr<int> sp2;
 sp.reset (new int);
 sp2.reset (new int);
 *sp=10;
 *sp2=400;
  sp2=sp;

 std::shared_ptr<int> sp3;
 sp3=sp1;
 //what happens with the int of value 400?
 //more code
}
```

what happens with the int of value 400? is this a memory leak? this is a basic example but if instead of int the pointers were pointing to a big class, then it would be problematic if there was a memory leak, and more if sp2 is reasigned more times.
thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to write `*sp = 10`? It would make more sense if you meant `sp=std::make_shared<int>(10);`.

Comment: yea sorry forgot those lines

Comment: Of course there's no leak, Since `sp2` is the sole owner of the int containing 400, it'll be destroyed before `sp2` takes shared ownership of the memory owned by `sp`.

Comment: The whole point of smart pointers is to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edits, no there's no leaks. The memory allocated for the `int` with the value `400` will simply be deleted for you in the assignment.